# Use title attribute of image field in rule

Tags: rules, media, tokens

I like to use the title value of a image field in a rule. The provided tokens for the image field do not contain title or alt attribute. I have only tokens for file:fid, file:name, file:mime, file:size, file:url, file:owner:..., file:type but nothing like file:title or file:alt.

I already had a look for a module providing title / alt value of image field as token but wasn't successful. I can't imagine I'm the first one who like to use title attribute in a rule. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using fieldable file entities on your site?  The answer depends on whether you are or not.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Module file entity is not installed.